# Case RecordTypeIdd field doesn't exists on Production

Tags: deployment, case, record-type, change-set

In my org, I have created some custom fields and record types and have written few triggers on case object. Now am trying to move all these components to production. When I try to move I get an error saying RecordTypeId field doesn't exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a recordtype manually in your production org and then try moving all toher components via change set. 
As there are no recordtype values created earlier in the production org, it says there is no **RecordTypeID** field in your production org. And when you create a value manually this enables **RecordTypeID** field and changeset works fine without error.

Comment: Try it worked:-)

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your Case object does not yet have any record types created for it. Include the record types with your change set. The API "usually" gets it right, but if not, you may need to migrate the record types in their own change set first before moving the related code.

Comment: I have included all records types in my change set along with the triggers still I get that error

Comment: @SFDev Yeah, every once in a while, Salesforce just doesn't get a deployment correct. Deploy the record types first before deploying your code.